# Rename folder with odd characters

Tags: osx, rm, character-encoding, mv, special-characters

I have a folder on my Mac called "␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data".  I'm trying to delete it but it contains a bunch of odd characters that are choking unlink, rm and mv, making it difficult to remove it and its contents.  I've tried whipping up some code to call unlink() directly just in case unlink/rm/mv binaries are doing some other stuff - but no, unlink() can't parse this character.

I used echo and od to figure out what character this is:

```
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ echo -e "␀" | od -t oC -An
      342 220 200 012`
```

I looked up 342 here: http://ascii-code.com - and found that it's part of the Latin-1 set.  I tried iconv to convert it to UTF-8:

```
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 "␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data"
iconv: ␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data: I/O error
```

So how do I delete this folder?  Can I pass hex/oct codes to rm or mv or something?  I've tried everything I can think of, including rm *, invoking sudo, etc.  The problem is that unlink chokes on that character, so I need to change that character somehow.  I was also thinking about installing Debian in a VM and giving it access to this folder so that I could try from there, in case this is an issue with the tools I have in my OS X environment.

EDIT:
I tried this:

```
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ echo -e "␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data" | od -t oC -An
      342 220 200 342 220 200 342 220 200 110 106 123 053 040 120 162
      151 166 141 164 145 040 104 141 164 141 012`

************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ echo "\342\220\200\342\220\200\342\220\200\110\106\123\053\040\120\162\151\166\141\164\145\040\104\141\164\141\012" | xargs rm

rm: 342220200342220200342220200110106123053040120162151166141164145040104141164141012:     No such file or directory

************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ echo "\342"
\342
```

EDIT2: showing the unlink() error

```
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ unlink test3.txt
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ unlink "␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data/1.txt"
unlink: ␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data/1.txt: Invalid argument
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ cd "␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data/"
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test/␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data$ unlink 1.txt
unlink: 1.txt: Invalid argument
```

EDIT3: showing that it's not an HFS+/filesystem issue, but rather a filename issue

```
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ mkdir "␀␀␀␀testTest"
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ rm -r "␀␀␀␀testTest"
rm: ␀␀␀␀testTest: Invalid argument
```

EDIT4: this might be progress... I'm going to mess with the locale next.

```
************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ ls | grep -i *test* | xxd
0000000: e290 80e2 9080 e290 80e2 9080 7465 7374  ............test
0000010: 5465 7374 0a                             Test.

************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ rm -r $'\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\x74\x65\x73\x74\x54\x65\x73\x74\x0a'
rm: ␀␀␀␀testTest
: No such file or directory

Follow-up to this: nope, false hope.  I dropped the \x0a on the end and it 'worked'... kind of.

************@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ rm -r $'\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\xe2\x90\x80\x74\x65\x73\x74\x54\x65\x73\x74'
rm: ␀␀␀␀testTest: Invalid argument
```

Comment: The odd characters and the "I/O error" make it sound a lot like filesystem corruption.  Have you run a disk check recently?

Comment: @DavidKing I know, but it's not.  This is a re-creation of an error on my client's machine, and both of them are clean in terms of filesystem corruption.  The I/O error shows up in iconv but in all the other utilities where unlink() is involved it's a different error.

Comment: What is the other error?

Comment: @DavidKing see edit2.  The code I whipped up (a few lines of C++ basically just calling unlink()), had the same error.  Invalid argument.

Comment: Thanks @don_crissti. How did you find that question? I've favorited it so that I can link back here if I do find a solution.

Comment: have you tried `rm -fr *HFS+ Private Data` or mv `*HFS+ Private Data HFS+ Private Data`

Comment: Hah, I tried creating a file named `␀` on my mac and now I can't get rid of it. I was able to make it hidden though.

Comment: Hah! Don't do it folks..

Comment: I am wondering if the `␀` characters ( [printf '%b' '\U2400'](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9216&number=128) should be in fact `nul` (`\0`) characters. Yes, you do have several hex outputs (od, xxd) that negate my guess. But still, a simple `ls -lai` to see the inode of the problematic file and that may show something different. .... Also try to rm the file with it's inode number: `find . -inum [inode-number] -exec rm -i {} \;` [link](https://superuser.com/questions/143125/remove-a-file-on-linux-using-the-inode-number).

Comment: @BinaryZebra: I did try deletion by inode, same issue because (apparently) it finds the filename and passes that to rm. I'll try the other shortly!

Comment: @Harv Well, also try `find . -inum [inode-number] -delete`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: I tried the NUL's.  It recognized it but still can't remove it..  as for find -delete, same output... because find -delete calls unlink().

Comment: @Harv : I feel your pain. :-( Sorry. Booting to a Linux distro seems to be the only solution.

Comment: @don_crissti amazing! Thank you, please submit as an answer and I'll select it once I've done it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried simply renaming the folder to something else then deleting it?

A method that has worked for me was to live boot into a Linux  environment via CD/USB,  dismount the drive with the 'odd' named directory/file,  THEN deleting it. This method  works most of the time, not every, for me.

Comment: I wish... while I haven't booted from a Linux LiveCD (I'd have to decrypt my entire partition for one), I did install Debian in a VM and give it full read/write access. Same problem. The rm binary itself seems unable to deal with this character. I also tried Windows 7 Pro. I've lined up a few other distributions to try, in the hopes they might have a different rm utility: PCLinuxOS, OpenSUSE, Fedora and Slackware. I'm getting desperate...

Comment: A VM also use the underlying OS filesystem. Try booting to a real linux OS. Testing in a Debian system, the directory could be created and erased at will without any problem.

Comment: Thanks, Edgar.  I finally got around to this today.
To add some details and clarification: I had to decrypt my volume (FileVault2 was enabled), get Ubuntu onto a bootable USB key (I just used Parallels/Windows 7 + Rufus + the ISO), installed rEFInd, rebooted into Ubuntu, dismounted the OS X volume because it mounts automatically as RO, re-mounted it as RW and deleted the directory.  Back into OS X, re-enabled FV2, and away I go.

Answer (score 3):

According to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31734/hfs-private-directory-data that folder is used for filesystem inner workings.  You probably *can't* delete it and, even if you could, it would most likely brick your filesystem.

Comment: Understood, but actually that folder is from an old backup, not currently actually in use. I'm trying to remove old data. Also the re-created version on my machine isn't special in any way, I just use mkdir and pasted the filename, so IMO it's not the case of a special filesystem node or anything like that, it's a filename issue.

Comment: You keep shooting down all my good ideas :(  Is it actually on an HFS+ filesystem?

Comment: Sorry man.  I appreciate the help.  Yes, HFS+.

Comment: It's not a problem I just thought I had this solved for you a few times now.  I'm guessing that HFS has protections built in to prevent deletion of that folder even if it isn't the actual folder that HFS is using.

Comment: I have the same issue if I create a folder called "␀␀␀␀Test" and try to rm -r it.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has already been resolved for OP, but for anyone stumbling upon this question, this seems to be a 10.11 El Capitan only problem. I tried and was able to delete files with this character in OS X 10.4 Tiger and OS X 10.10 Yosemite, so it very likely works on the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI:

The "␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data" folder is an HFS+ special folder that is used to hold the actual file-data and meta-data for hard-linked files.

So multiple directory-entries point to a 'file' in this hidden directory, which in turn has the actual file-data and atributes attached.

It has some special attributes like the four leading ZERO characters in the name, as well as a few other bits in its meta-data to make it very unlikely it is ever 'seen' by the end-user in normal use.

When found in some backup (so no live copy) as a visible folder you can safely remove it, if the system allows you to do so (perhaps after low-level renaming with a hex-editor or other tool.

There is a similar hidden file called ".HFS+ Private Directory Data" that is used to store hard-link info on folders.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a *(retired?)* [spec here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#HFSPlusNames):

> Indirect node files exist in a special directory called the *metadata directory*. This directory exists in the volume's root directory. The name of the metadata directory is **four null characters** followed by the string *HFS+ Private Data*. The directory's creation date is set to the creation date of the volume's root directory. The *kIsInvisible* and *kNameLocked* bits are set in the directory's Finder information. The icon location in the Finder info is set to the point *(22460, 22460)*. These Finder info settings are not mandatory, but they tend to reduce accidental changes to the metadata directory. **An implementation that automatically follows hard links should make the metadata directory inaccessable from its normal file system interface**.
>
> > **Note:**
> >
> > > The case-insensitive Unicode string comparison used by HFS Plus and case-insensitive HFSX sorts null characters after all other characters, so the metadata directory will typically be the last item in the root directory. On case-sensitive HFSX volumes, null characters sort before other characters, so the metadata directory will typically be the first item in the root directory.
>
> POSIX semantics allow an open file to be *unlinked* (deleted). These open but unlinked files are stored on HFS Plus volumes much like a hard link. When the open file is deleted, it is renamed and moved into the metadata directory. The new name is the string "temp" followed by the catalog node ID converted to decimal text. When the file is eventually closed, this temporary file may be removed. All such temporary files may be removed when repairing an unmounted HFS Plus volume.
>
> > **Repairing the Metadata Directory**
> >
> > When repairing an HFS Plus volume with hard links or a metadata directory, there are several conditions that might need to be repaired:
> >
> > - Opened but deleted files (which are now orphaned).
> > - Orphaned indirect node files (no hard links refer to them).
> > - Broken hard link (hard link exists, but indirect node file does not).
> > - Incorrect link count.
> > - Link reference was 0.
> >
> > Opened but deleted files are files whose names start with "temp", and are in the metadata directory. **If the volume is not in use (not mounted, and not being used by any other utility), then these files can be deleted**. Volumes with a journal, even one with no active transactions, may have opened but undeleted files that need to be deleted.
> >
> > Detecting an orphaned indirect node file, broken hard link, or incorrect link count requires finding all hard link files in the catalog, and comparing the number of found hard links for each link reference with the link count of the corresponding indirect node file.
> >
> > A hard link with a link reference equal to 0 is invalid. Such a hard link may be the result of a hard link being copied or restored by an implementation or utility that does not use the permissions in catalog records. It may be possible to repair the hard link by determining the proper link reference. Otherwise, the hard link should be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the work to find and post that.  However, we're not actually dealing with the HFS+ Private Data folder on a live system, this is a remenant of an old system and I'm trying to delete old data that's not in use.  But also, I was able to insert this problematic character into another folder name and have it also not deletable - so it's a filesystem/unlink() bug, as opposed to a limitation of this being a special folder.  Any folder or file with this special character isn't removable on my system.

Comment: @Harv - I don't think it can't be both. if you look through that link you'll notice a lot of stuff about special *reserved fields*. I'm assuming that the filesystem bug is interpreting any file which fits its expectation of its namespace to actually be in its namespace. So I would think the solution would be to treat the file as it does and repair it likewise - that's the first way I would go, anyway. And the docs said that such problems might only be addressed offline and unmounted.

Comment: oh interesting.  So you think the special character (even on my system as opposed to where the bug first showed up - on another system), indicates to the fs somehow that this is a special folder.  Is that accurate?

Comment: @Harv - well, it talks about how unlinking cant be done online. and so it *sounds* like your issue. and the filenames are pretty similar...? i dunno what you mean by *even on my system as opposed to...* but it does also mention *failed backups* in the same paragraph. it is an HFS filesystem, yes?

Comment: HFS+. I replicated the problem on my own system (after discovering it on a client's machine), then found that the existence of those weird characters in any folder name causes the same problem. If I insert that character and call the file or folder "test" it exhibits the same behaviour. That lead me to think it's not a special file or folder, but a problem in unlink() that it can't process that character.

Comment: @Harv why would `unlink()` care, really? it should only handle descriptors in the main. the lib c might break at the nulls, yeah, so maybe, yeah. but there is also stuff about how the old FORTRAN utilities are massaged into understanding its Unicode 16 encoding. it's a *long* link. but i don't think these two things are so dissimilar - if you write a filesystem you have to provide an `unlink()`. so its the fs's problem, still. and the spec for the fs is at that link, where a lot of problems similar to yours are at least halfway addressed - *you should read it*. i think you need to offline rep

Comment: I wrote some simple C++ code that took an argument and passed it along to unlink().  Same problem.  So yeah, why does unlink() care?  I don't know, but it does, and it can't unlink files with that character.  I don't know why.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Harv - there are two illegal characters in a POSIX-like fs - filename: `/` and `\0`. so that's probably why *if* its why. and maybe it is why - but maybe it's also why the other files are spec'd not removable online as well. definitely they have a lot in common. i think you need to unmount and do the repair. that's what's' the docs say - what can it hurt to try?

Comment: agreed.  I did try booting my system into its recovery partition - but you can't repair with the volume unmounted.  How do I do that on any system?  I didn't think you could repair unmounted.  How would that even work?  Anyway, booted into my recovery partition, repairing the volume had no effect on those files and folders.

Comment: @Harv - i dunno - i don't have a Mac, but the spec was pretty clear about this point: ***If the volume is not in use (not mounted, and not being used by any other utility), then these files can be deleted.*** I assume there's some fschk management utility you're supposed to use.

Comment: not without mounting the volume.  But even on Linux - you can't fsck a partition without first at least mounting it read-only.  I don't understand...

Comment: @Harv - that depends on the fs. some fs's do the check offline - at least btrfs used to require it. there is the example code for [*Fast Unicode String Compare*](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties)... but i'm not sure if that's supposed to be done offline. but basically if you're doing an offline fs check then you'll be reading the device per fs maps - why would you want it mounted? i dunno how its done, i just know that's what it says.

Comment: @Harv, then again, maybe not: [*Why am I getting a `bdNmErr` for a file I just located?*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1392/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time with Apple Support on this and they told me the only answer was to do a Time Machine backup of my volume, wipe the original volume, create a new user account and then selectively copy all my files over manually from the Time Machine backup. Realizing the work this would entail in restoring my wonderfully complex account with all my preferences, setups, software authorisations, scripts, handy utilities, etc, I didn't want to do that so I had another idea that worked for me.

I worked out that I could move the immediate folder above the undeleteable file, so I corralled all the files I had with the null characters that nothing would allow me to delete them with into another folder, and then created a Carbon Copy Cloner clone of my entire boot HDD, but excluding the folder with the undeleteables. I then booted into this disk, reformatted my original disk, and restored the clone, sans the undeletable files.

When someone works out how to make the various Unix based OSes deals with these file names, we'll all be very happy, but in the meantime, CCC to the rescue for me.

Comment: See the accepted answer and comments here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254276/how-to-delete-without-rm-unlink/254283#254283