# How to delete, without rm/unlink

Tags: filesystems, osx, delete

Related to another question I asked [here [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253932/rename-folder-with-odd-characters]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253932/rename-folder-with-odd-characters)

I'm wondering if it's possible to bypass the normal `rm`/`rmdir`/`unlink` binaries and delete a file using another method.  Maybe say by finding out exactly where on the disk a file or folder resides, and writing different data to that location, wiping out the folder or file.  How would one go about doing that, and would it cause problems for the OS or filesystem?

Or, is there a .. I hesitate to call it a file but an area of the disk that can be viewed and edited with a hex editor, say, to find and unlink the exact reference to this folder/file?  And then, is there a different way of doing that specific to HFS+ and/or OS X?

EDIT1: I'm interested not in deleting the contents of a file here, I'm interested in removing a file and/or folder using methods outside of `rm`/`unlink`.  I'm not trying to get rid of data in a forensic sense, I'm trying to remove a folder that refuses to be removed (see question I linked to above).

Comment: @PSKocik I saw you respond to another question just now mentioning root can write to a disk bypassing the FS.  Maybe you could elaborate on that here, if you know how.  Pretty please?

Comment: You would need to have the disk unmounted and not in use for this to be a safe procedure. If you're going to do that you might as well go for the Linux Rescue Disk approach suggested elsewhere.

Comment: @roaima: could you submit that as an answer with a link to the rescue disk approach you mentioned?

Comment: Depends a lot on level you are willing to go. In short you could read up on and learn how the file-system is built from ground up. If you acquire this knowledge - it would (of course) only be to write a tool to do what ever you want. A mid way could be to look into **forensics** (as a key-word) and tools available for that. http://www.sleuthkit.org/index.php is a quick example. You would have to find some for *your* FS though  of course. Had this: https://books.google.no/books?id=Zpm9CgAAQBAJ in my book-shelf many years ago (someone borrowed and its gone). But in *that* direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing a disk image is possible, but very risky. If you have a suitable editor that can help you with this it would be worth making sure that you have a copy (written or otherwise) of the data you're changing.

Most importantly, it must not be attempted without the disk being unmounted and not in use. If it's your boot/system disk that means you are going to have to use a separate mechanism to boot, such as a rescue disk.

My preferred Linux-based Rescue CD is [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage), but it's not certain that it contains HFS tools (the list of packages suggests it might). Here is [another possible solution](https://abhinay.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/repair-fix-mac-hfs-partition-using-ubuntu-cd/), using a standard Ubuntu installation disk, but it's from 2009 so it may well be *extremely out of date*.

Comment: Thank you, that helps, but how's it done?

Comment: @Harv I'd boot the CD, mount the filesystem and try deleting the file. Pragnatically I prefer KISS until that's proven not to work

Comment: I went with decrypting my FileVault2 volume and booting into Ubuntu - details here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253932/rename-folder-with-odd-characters

Your answer was the closest, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the original data continuing to exist, and you just want to delete files that you can't delete directly due to character encoding issues then this is your solution. It involves using rename to rename the files so they may be deleted. The example below will remove all NON-ASCII characters from all file and directory names in the current directory.

```
rename 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' ./*
rm new-filenames
```

The regular expression `[^\x00-\x7F]` came from this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124010/grep-regex-to-match-non-ascii-characters)

To traverse into sub-directories use find:

```
find . -exec rename -n 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' "{}" \;
```

remove the -n flag to have it do the renaming instead of just tell you which files it would have renamed.

Comment: Nope ..
`ashleyharvey@Trinity:~/Desktop/test$ rename 's/␀//g' ./*`

`Can't rename './␀␀␀␀HFS+ Private Data' to './HFS+ Private Data': Invalid argument`

`Can't rename './␀␀␀␀testTest' to './testTest': Invalid argument`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. You need to use the character code, not the character itself. I will adjust my answer to remove all NON-ASCII characters.

Comment: I tried both...

Comment: Try `rename 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' ./*`

Comment: same issue.  I don't think you understand - the issue isn't that the system doesn't recognize which folder or file to rename - it does.  The problem is that once it tries to do the renaming or deleting thing, it can't.  The invalid argument error comes from unlink() trying to parse the filename.  Which happens with rm, unlink, rename, mv, and find so far.  If it couldn't find the path, it would display a different message, which is that the path is invalid.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I would suspect a bug in your tools then. Try mounting the disk from Linux.